# Find a way to find characters that doesn't match the Regex is javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a way to determine which character in my string does not match the regex, is there a way to do so in Javascript?

I've been using the regex object and i was able to determine whether a string matches the regex but i would like to go step further to determine why a string does not match the regex.

any thoughts?

This was what I currently have ... i am just trying to make sure
a string only contains the set of characters found in the following regex ... 
and i would like to see which character does not match.

Here's my code :

```
var regexTest = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z\\!\\040\\@\\s\\#\\$\\%\\&\\*\\(\\)\\_\\+\\:\\\"\\<\\>\\?\\-\\=\\;\\'\\,\\.\\\\]+$",g);

var bValid = regexTest.test(value); //this will check whether the value is valid ...
```

I've tried using `value = value.replace(regexTest,'')`, but was unable to actually filter out the characters.

Comment: I don't think this is really well defined in general. Which character in `"aababb"` doesn't match the regex `/^a*b*$/`? Which character in `"aaaccc"` doesn't match the regex `/^a+b+c+$/`? Which character in `""` (ie: the empty string) doesn't match the regex `/a+/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could replace all the characters that *do* match with `''`, leaving only the things that don't match:

```
'abc123'.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, '')
// "123"
```

Comment: Ah, you meant catch the unmatched terms. Apologies, I misread. The above will sort your problem

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite work - i've edited the question for some more clarity.

Comment: What does your huge regex do? Can you provide a test string?

Comment: I did - just updated the question. Eventually decided to check the string one character as a time - don't think that's too nice of a solution but works for now.